# Can someone guide me to run my API tests locally using AWS-SAM?

Tags: web-api-testing, aws-serverless, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I have a postman collection for my API tests. I want to know if I can use the same when my dev team revamps the project stack to AWS. If so, is there any quick guide for API testing using AWS-SAM? If not, then how should I go about testing my API's?

Comment: I haven't used this recently, but if the api is simple enough you should be able to use `sam local start-api`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html

Comment: This apparently solves the basic issue. 
This will trigger the postman collection saved in your project, run the tests and save the reports.

`code`

    phases:
    prebuild:
    commands:
    - npm install newman --global

    build:
    commands:
    - newman run -r html, 
    cli YOUR_PROJECT_API_TESTSCRIPT.postman_collection.json --reporter- 
    html-export report.html

    artifacts:
    files:
    - report.html